# FullCalendar not loading in Boostrap 4 tab

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 tabs, and on the second tab I would like to display a calendar using the `FullCalendar` library. The version of FullCalendar I'm using is `5.2.0`. The calendar works fine if it is displayed on the first tab, since it is not hidden; however, it does not load when it is part of the second tab.

I tried to solve this issue by triggering a JavaScript event click when the user clicks on the second tab. Basically, I tried to render the calendar after user clicked on the tab, but to no success.

Here's my code:

```
<!-- Tabs -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#today">Today</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="calendarButton" data-toggle="tab" href="#week">Week</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Tabs Content -->
<div class="tab-content">

    <!-- Appointments -->
    <div class="tab-pane container" id="today">
        <p> Appointments </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Weekly Calendar -->
    <div class="tab-pane container" id="week">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="calendar"></div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarButton = document.getElementById('calendarButton');
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

          themeSystem: 'bootstrap',

          headerToolbar: {
            right: 'listWeek'
          },

          events: [
                        {% for appointment in appointments %}
                        {
                            title: "{{ appointment.name}}",
                            start: '{{ appointment.start }}',
                            end: '{{ appointment.end }}',
                        },
                        {% endfor %}
                   ]
        });

        calendarButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
            calendar.render();
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I load the calendar after clicking on the second tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround by delaying the rendering of the calendar. If anyone finds it helpful, to display the calendar you can replace `calendar.render()` in my code above with `setTimeout(() => {calendar.render()}, 1)`.