# render of fullcalendar with tab

Tags: bootstrap-4, tabs, fullcalendar, render

I am trying to implement Fullcalendar in a nav-tab. The template engine I am using is Thymeleaf and Bootstrap 4.

However there is a issue of rendering issue. When I run the server, Fullcalendar is displayed as shown in the first image.

[image]

However, after modifying the page scale, Fullcalendar is changed as shown in the second image.

[image]

I would like to know the reason for this issue and possible solutions.

Here is my code to help you understand.

```
    <!-- fullcalendar 추가부분-->
    <script src='/fullcalendar/dist/index.global.js'></script>
    <script>

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
              editable: false,
              selectable: false,
              businessHours: true,
              dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
              events: [
                {
                  title: 'Conference',
                  start: '2023-01-11',
                  end: '2020-09-13'
                },
                {
                  title: 'Meeting',
                  start: '2023-01-12T10:30:00',
                  end: '2023-01-12T12:30:00'
                },
                {
                  title: 'Dinner',
                  start: '2023-01-12T20:00:00'
                },
                {
                  title: 'Birthday Party',
                  start: '2023-01-13T07:00:00'
                }
              ]
            });
        
            calendar.render();
          });

    </script>

 <!-- Nav tabs -->
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="calendarTab">
    <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">
              <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">기안문</h6>
         </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">
              <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">연차 달력</h6>
         </a>
    </li>
 </ul>

<!-- card-body -->
<div class="card-body">

      <!-- tab-content -->
      <div class="tab-content">
                                
        <!-- tab-content1 -->
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1"></div>


        <!-- tab-content2 -->
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                                        
              <div id="calendar"></div>
                                    
        
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72875480/fullcalendar-doesnt-render-inside-a-bootstrap-tab

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63386117/fullcalendar-not-loading-in-boostrap-4-tab

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795282/full-calendar-is-not-loading-automatically-in-bootstrap-tab